# Get a ContentResolver within a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter

I've recently begun teaching myself Android development. Right now I'm making an app that shows a list of boxes; clicking on a box shows its contents. Each row view in the main list has a "delete" icon next to the box name. My ListAdapter is a subclass of `CursorAdapter`. In the `bindView()` method of `CursorAdapter`, I do the following:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_box_name);
    name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.BoxEntry.NAME)));
    name.setFocusable(false);
    ImageButton delete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_box_delete);
    delete.setFocusable(false);
    delete.setTag(cursor.getLong(0));
    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            long id = ((Long) view.getTag());
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I've tagged each ImageButton with the ID of the box it should delete. What I would like to be able to do here is this:

```
getContentResolver().delete(uri...);
```

This code would tell my custom `ContentProvider` to delete that box and all its contents. The obvious problem is that from the context of my `CursorAdapter`, I can't call `getContextResolver`. What would be the best way to go about talking to my `ContentProvider` from within the `CursorAdapter`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Context` contains the method [getContentResolver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver%28%29) therefore you can write your `bindView` as:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_box_name);
    name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.BoxEntry.NAME)));
    name.setFocusable(false);
    ImageButton delete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_box_delete);
    delete.setFocusable(false);
    delete.setTag(cursor.getLong(0));
    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            long id = ((Long) view.getTag());
            context.getContentResolver().delete(uri...);
        }
    });
```

}

Note that your `context` must be `final` in order to reference it in the anonymous inner class.

Comment: Thank you! I'm surprised I missed that. I would upvote but I lack the reputation :)